# EventBus and Proguard: Could not dispatch event

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to export a signed app and when I run my app i get this exception

```
Could not dispatch event: class com.achlan.myapp.events.e to subscribing class class com.achlan.myapp.b.d
```

mapping.txt:

```
com.achlan.myapp.events.RestResult -> com.achlan.myapp.events.e
com.achlan.myapp.data.DataManager -> com.achlan.myapp.b.d:
```

I've already added this line to my proguard config:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
public void onEvent*(**); }
```

Am I missing something in my proguard config?

Comment: Without more of the stack trace, there is not a lot that I can suggest, other than perhaps filing an issue on the EventBus issue tracker.

Answer (score 5):

I also had an issue with EventBus and ProGuard and I contacted the creator of ProGuard/DexGuard and he sent me the following 'workaround' which might help:

```
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class ** { public void onEvent*(**); }
```

Add `includedescriptorclasses` to your config file to prevent ProGuard/DexGuard's optimization step to add a suffix to the method name.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse the method. I do like this:

If I use

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this, "getName", Name.class);
```

I will do

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void getName(**);
}
```

It can work.

Comment: you need to explain your answer.

Comment: thank you, but I am trying to do it without declaring the receiving eventbus function. anyway, I've tried your solution and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a non public (package private) onEvent method you will need to update your progaurd config as follows:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
    void onEvent*(**);
}
```

Comment: thanks but every onEvent method in my code is public.

Comment: If you have `void onEvent*(**);`, I don't think you'll need `public void onEvent*(**);`.